# Enum type as parameter in constructor

Tags: c#, parameters, enums

I am making a file dialog an need to be able to pass a file type mask as part of the constructor. If possible, i would like to store these masks as Enums. Here's an example below:

```
public enum ImageFileMask {
    Bmp,
    Dds,
    Dib,
    Hdr,
    Jpg,
    Pfm,
    Png,
    Ppm,
    Tga
}
```

I then check when i chose a file, if it belongs to the file mask using the following line:

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(ImageFileMask.GetType(), extension))
```

(extension being the file extension of the chosen file).

This all worked well and good, until i decided that my file dialog will need to accept different file types at different times. I was hoping that i could pass any enum type through the constructor to be stored an evaluated during the file dialog.

The issue is, is that i cannot find a way to get the enum type to be accepted as a parameter in my constructor.

```
new FileDialogMenu(ImageFileMask);
```

I always get the following error:

```
ImageFileMask is a 'type' but is used like a 'variable'
```

I have tried changing the constructor to take a `Type`, but this has not worked. Is what i am trying even possible? Or do i need to take a different approach to storing the mask.

Comment: use either typeof or generics.

Comment: Do you want to pass the type of the enum to the constructor?

Comment: Yes,  I can the just replace what I have with the passed type

Comment: Then your method should accept `Type` as a parameter, and you can use `typeof(ImageFileMask)`

Comment: Well that makes perfect sense.  Now I feel stupid!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If i understand your question, you want to pass the type of the enum to the constructor of your class, something like this:

```
class FileDialogMenu
{
    readonly Type enumType;

    public FileDialogMenu(Type enumType)
    {
        this.enumType = enumType;
    }
}
```

If so you have no problem at doing this:

```
new FileDialogMenu(typeof(ImageFileMask));
```

And the you can do (inside your `FileDialogMenu` class):

```
if (Enum.IsDefined(enumType, extension))
```

Well at least that is what i've understood.

Answer (score 0):

To expand on Daniel's comment, you'll want to declare something like

```
FileDialogMenu<E> where E : BaseEnum
```

Where BaseEnum is the parent class of all the appropriate ImageFileMask and related enums.

[This link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/d5x73970.aspx) may help you.

Answer (score 0):

You could change the enum to contain all possible types, and make it a [Flags] enum:

```
[Flags]
public enum ImageFileMask {
    ....
```

Then your constructor could haven an `ImageFileMask allowedImages` parameter:

```
var x = new FileDialogMenu(ImageFileMask.Bmp | ImageFileMask.Jpg);
```

Once you have a file, you could perform a bitwise comparison:

```
ImageFileMask extension = ...
if ((allowedImages & extension) == extension)
{
    // the extension is allowed
}
```

Of course if the enum would grow too large, you could also consider simply supplying a `List<string>` instead.